# html select - range of 0-10

Tags: javascript, html

If I want to give a choice of 0-10 in five different selects, is there HTML code for this (non HTML5) that allows me to not repeat the choices for each of the five selects, or do I have to repeat this code?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not even use javascript?

Comment: Is this code trivial to do in JS?  Thanks.

Comment: you probably already know this, but if not, store the options in a variable (javascript or otherwise), and just use it for each select. really...  javascript is good for that kind of thing

Comment: Thanks -- code snippet would be very helpful.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do it in JS and avoid writing out all the choices over and over. Although, for 10 choices and a modern IDE, copy-and-paste is relatively painless... is there some larger maintenance overhead you are trying to avoid, such as having to update the choices down the road?  In the time it took you to write the question, you could already have it finished...

Comment: ... it just seems ugly (and long) to repeat it.  Additionally, I will probably take 0-15 or 0-20, so the list is even bigger.

Comment: It is better to use a single text input field instead of a select element with options 0 to 10. Even more so if the limit is 15 or 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to repeat the code if you use just HTML

Answer (score 4):

really, consider using JS for that.

some example html:

```
<select id="someSelect">

</select>
```

your script:

```
var options = "";
for(var i = 1; i<11; i++ ) {
    options += "<option value="+i+">+i+</option>";
```

//EDIT summary:there was no string concatanation

```
}
```

then just set the html value of your select equal to that variable:

```
document.getElementById('someSelect').innerHTML = options;
```

or if you were using jquery:

```
$('#someSelect').html( options );
```

Comment: Far better to put that logic on the server and just serve the plain HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) and its directive "ng-repeat" for that.

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
   <p>something with {{choice}}</p>
</div>
```